# Converting a dynamic web project from netbeans to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, netbeans, war

I tried to convert the java based dynamic web project for netbeans into eclipse.
I converted the project to a war and then imported into eclipse. But, this did not
work and I saw that all java package contain nothing. How do I fix this thing ?

The project is at - https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples%252FJavaEE%252Fecommerce%252FAffableBean_snapshot5.zip

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My solution was:

1. Open a new Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. (pref. 2.5)
2. Copy Net Beans WEB-INF folder(webapps or something else like jsp,html,css) and paste to Eclipse WEB-INF(webapps) folder or change.
3. Copy Net Beans Java classes and paste to Eclipse Java folder.
4. If you have library copy and paste to Eclipse from Net Beans.
5. Clean and Build.